# I'm getting unexpected top header in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation's createBottomTabNavigator for tab component in react-native.
The problem is that I'm getting unnecessary top header.

[This image is what I'm getting now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Gpv.png)

I want to remove the top header.
Please help me.

This is my navigator code.

```
import HomeContainer from 'src/mainView/homeContainer'
import CameraPage from 'src/mainView/pages/cameraPage'
import CarOwnerVoicePage from 'src/mainView/pages/carOwnerVoicePage'
import ProfileContainer from 'src/profile'

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    home: {screen: HomeContainer},
    carOwnerVoice: {screen: CarOwnerVoicePage},
    camera: {screen: CameraPage},
    profile: {screen: ProfileContainer}
  },
  { 
    headerMode: 'none' ,
    tabBarOptions: {
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 15,
        marginBottom: 10,
        padding: 0,
      },
    },
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Comment: try adding `navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null,
    })`

Comment: I have tried this, but not working with tab-navigator. This is to hide the bottom tab bar, but what I want is to hide the top header in the image.
In the tab navigator demo, the top header doesn't appear. But in my app, it appears. :(

Comment: can you add code of your all navigators?

Comment: OK. I added the code.

Comment: where are you added the navigationOptions that i suggested ?

Comment: In every pages, I added static navigationOptions variable with your value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake.
This TabNavigator is used as a screen in another navigator and that was the problem.

```
const MainView = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

MainView.navigationOptions={
  header: null
}

export default MainView;
```

I changed the code and it works now.
Thanks for your effort and advice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide on specific screen than do like this:

```
// create a component
export default class Login extends Component<{}> {
  static navigationOptions = { header: null };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find more description from [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html).

Please try below code, It may solve your problem.

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    home: {screen: HomeContainer},
    carOwnerVoice: {screen: CarOwnerVoicePage},
    camera: {screen: CameraPage},
    profile: {screen: ProfileContainer}
  },
  { 
    tabBarOptions: {
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 15,
        marginBottom: 10,
        padding: 0,
      },
    },
  }
);

TabNavigator.navigationOptions={
    header:null,
}

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Comment: Thanks. @Patel Dhara. I have tried this one, but it seems it doesn't work for me.

Comment: did you get any error? or can you please share your code where you import this TabNavigator?